# R - Generate Histogram, given a vector of bar heights

Tags: r, plot

I have a vector of length 14, where each entry in the vector is to represent the height of a histogram bar. For example, given this vector

```
> sample(1:20, 14)
 [1]  3 11  5 14 12  6 18  2  8  4 17 13 19 15
```

I want to generate a histogram with 14 bars, where the first bar has height 3, the second has height 11, etc.
For some reason, this is harder than I think it should be. I can't seem to find anything about it online, or maybe I'm not good at searching. If this has been answered elsewhere, please direct me to it.

Comment: It doesn't sound like you're actually trying to make a histogram. What you 're describing sounds more like a bar plot.

Comment: You're right. I'm sorry for the misunderstanding. I didn't realize the difference between the two. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

```
x <- c(3, 11,  5, 14, 12,  6, 18,  2,  8,  4, 17, 13, 19, 15)
barplot(x)
```

Comment: a bar plot is not a histogram

Comment: @dww read between lines, What the OP is asking for isn´t a histogram, so my answer is valid.